# Is there a way to use the result of a SELECT as a column identifier in a query? (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql

I need to do a query like this

```
select * from calendar where (select to_char(now(), 'day')) = true;
```

but this is invalid and fails with `ERROR:  failed to find conversion function from unknown to boolean`.

The query I'm trying write, when run today would boil down to

```
select * from calendar where thursday = true;
```

But tomorrow, it should be

```
select * from calendar where friday = true;
```

The table has this schema

```
mbta=# \d calendar
             Table "public.calendar"
   Column   |          Type          | Modifiers 
------------+------------------------+-----------
 service_id | character varying(255) | not null
 monday     | boolean                | 
 tuesday    | boolean                | 
 wednesday  | boolean                | 
 thursday   | boolean                | 
 friday     | boolean                | 
 saturday   | boolean                | 
 sunday     | boolean                | 
 start_date | integer                | 
 end_date   | integer                |
```

How can I write this query correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an ugly schema... A bunch of alternatives:

1. Replace 'monday, tuesday... ' fields by a single integer field, to be interpreted as a bit mask  - or use the [bit-string data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/datatype-bit.html)
2. Replace them by a single field that contatins an array of integers (days of week).
3. Denormalize to an extra table, with a single day_of_week field and a FK to your calendar table.

Comment: Thanks I'll take your advice and change the schema.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a solution.  Obviously, you can't use the result of a subselect in place of a column, but you can rearrange the relation to suit that sort of query.  First, build a subselect that transposes the individual columns into a single column

```
SELECT calendar.*, 'monday' AS weekday, monday AS dayvalue FROM calendar
UNION ALL
SELECT calendar.*, 'tuesday' AS weekday, tuesday AS dayvalue FROM calendar
UNION ALL
SELECT calendar.*, 'wednesday' AS weekday, wednesday AS dayvalue FROM calendar
UNION ALL
SELECT calendar.*, 'thursday' AS weekday, thursday AS dayvalue FROM calendar
UNION ALL
SELECT calendar.*, 'friday' AS weekday, friday AS dayvalue FROM calendar
UNION ALL
SELECT calendar.*, 'saturday' AS weekday, saturday AS dayvalue FROM calendar
UNION ALL
SELECT calendar.*, 'sunday' AS weekday, sunday AS dayvalue FROM calendar
```

Then you can wrap this all up as a subselect and pick out just the rows with the right weekday:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT calendar.*, 'monday' AS weekday, monday AS dayvalue FROM calendar
    UNION ALL
    SELECT calendar.*, 'tuesday' AS weekday, tuesday AS dayvalue FROM calendar
    UNION ALL
    ...         -- You get the idea.
    UNION ALL
    SELECT calendar.*, 'sunday' AS weekday, sunday AS dayvalue FROM calendar
) AS ss WHERE to_char(now(), 'day') = ss.weekday AND dayvalue = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. I think it's a good sign that things will be easier if I change the schema.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from calendar where (to_char(now(), 'day') != 'Monday' || monday) && (to_char(now(), 'day') != 'Tuesday' || tuesday) && …
```

Given the new schema, I think something like this is your best bet.

Comment: I added some info above. Does this help?

Comment: Do you have the choice to modify your datastructure. You should have a second table to associate your calendar periods (start, end) with one or more day of the week. It would be easier to make your query then I think.

Comment: @dan: Very enlightening.  I revised my answer to take into account the new information.

Comment: I tried your query and I get `ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean || boolean`

Comment: @dan: Ah, sorry.  Too many languages.  SQL uses AND for && and OR for ||.